# C macro - unintended result

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define SQ(x) ((x)*(x))

main()
{
    int i = 1;
    while( i<=5 ){
        printf("result : %d\n", SQ(i++));
    }
}
```

execute window :

result : 2
result : 12
result : 30

I intended that:

result : 1
result : 4
result : 9
result : 16
result : 25

How should I modify this code?

Comment: And please tell me Why

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) printf("result = %d\n", SQ(i));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A macro may evaluate its argument more than once. This is because `#define` textually substitutes, with no regard for C language rules. The preprocessor replaces `SQ(i++)` with

```
((i++)*(i++))
```

In this expression, `i++` is done twice, and not once.

This is why the use of `#define` is not recommended. Write a regular function instead, for the behavior you desire. Or, call `SQ` with an argument of `i`, and only after the call, write `i++`:

```
SQ(i);
i++;
```

Answer (score 1):

`SQ(i++) -> (i++)*(i++)`

Use this:

```
printf("result : %d\n", SQ(i));
i++;
```